# How to deal with development churn

Tags: c++, git

I am finding myself in an awkward position:

1. I have to hack a certain file (about 700 lines of algorithmic code in main.cpp) to support a specific use case in a corporate environment.
2. The file is under heavy development by the original author (external to my company) and I only get to see infrequent "stable" versions, with development history stripped away.
3. There are no unit tests, and running an integration test is time consuming and not fully automated.

What's the least painful way to deal with this situation code-wise?  I am already re-basing my commits locally each time I get a new version.

To make that question a bit more concrete:
Which works better with git's rebasing/merging algorithms:

- Deleting code that conflicts with my use-case
- Using either multi-line comments or the pre-processor to locally disable the wrong (but probably still churning) code regions

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this file is to keep a version of the file in a version control system under your control. When a new version is shipped to you by the original author, check in the new version to your source code repository as a new version of the file. Create your builds using the latest version from your repository. That will allow you to go back to a previous version if needed.

Comment: I'm already doing development in git, and my git-fu is fairly strong.  This is about minimizing pain in a situation where I'm being forced to do things in a bad way version-control-wise.